# Windows 10 device not found in a dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 on separate disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have Windows 10 & Ubuntu 18.04 installed on their own disk.

- Windows 10 is installed on `sda` with it's own EFI partition on `/dev/sda1`
- Ubuntu 18.04 is installed on `sdb` with it's own EFI partition on `/dev/sdb1`
- BIOS is configured to boot `sdb`.

Once I reach the grub2 menu I can boot Ubuntu with no problems, but if I try to boot Windows `Windows Boot Manager (/dev/sda1/)` I get a device not found error and it goes back to the grub2 menu. If I force boot `sda` from BIOS. I can boot Windows with no problems.

So both boot/EFI works on their own, the problem seems to be grub unable to located the `sda1` location properly?

I've tried `boot-repair` numerous time and it didn't help. When I run `update-grub`, it seems to find the Windows EFI partition but seems to never configure it properly.

This is what I get when I run `update-grub`:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.15.0-20-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda1@/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

I've looked around but not quite sure how to proceed to make grub point to the right device/boot for Windows 10. Should I go into the current grub configuration and change the device manually, run a command that would make a new entry that point to the right place, if so what command or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to fix it.

If, like me, you keep getting `No device found errors: <UUID>` when trying to boot to Windows and you are sure the menu entry points to the right partitions (Running: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | sort --key 11 | cut -c40-`).

Look in your BIOS settings and make sure that Fastboot is `disabled`.